# How to vertically combine two editTexts in a linearlayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

This is my aim:

[image]

I have a `linearlayout` where everything is `centered` both `vertically` and `horizontally`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_edittext_form_bg"
        android:hint="Email or Username"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5pt"/>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_edittext_form_bg"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5pt"  />

...
```

I have been messing around trying to take out the `layout_margin`, but this affects all elements (even the ones underneath these two).

Is there any way for me to simply combine these two `edittexts` like in the picture without affecting my `linearlayout`?

Comment: If you want other components below this, you might need a nested `LinearLayout` which contains just the to `EditText`s in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_edittext_form_bg"
        android:hint="Email or Username"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
        android:layout_marginRight="5pt"
        />
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_edittext_form_bg"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5pt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
        android:layout_marginRight="5pt"
/>
...
```

Tell me if it works. :)